# Using H2 database while Development with Spring Boot is recomended?

Tags: database, spring, oracle, spring-boot, h2

I have a simple question if someone can use the H2 Database while development with spring boot and Spring Data JPA and after completing the development, shifting to database like oracle .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the in-memory database for production considering the limitations.

From Spring Docs (**31.1.1**),

> It is often convenient to develop applications by using an in-memory embedded database. Obviously, in-memory databases do not provide persistent storage. You need to populate your database when your application starts and be prepared to throw away data when your application ends.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

It is IMHO OK until you need to do some performance testing. Performance of H2 is worse than that of, e.g., PostgreSQL and Oracle.